# how to execute XML data in to phpmyadmin Database

Tags: mysql, sql, xml, phpmyadmin

Hear is my XML data set. I want to execute this file format in to phpMyAdmin database.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>
<NewDataSet>
    <company>
        <COM_CODE>Test Data</COM_CODE>
        <COM_NAME>Test Data</COM_NAME>
        <COM_ADDRESS>Test Data</COM_ADDRESS>
    </company>
</NewDataSet>
```

Comment: What does *execute this file format* mean? Only scripts not data are executed.

Comment: Do you want to store this XML data set as a individual field within your MySQL database or are you trying to import this so that "Test Data" goes to the "COM_CODE" column, and "Test Data" is imported to the "COM_NAME" column, and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two functions available for providing basic `XPath 1.0 (XML Path Language, version 1.0)` in `MySQL`.Which are

> `ExtractValue()`:Extracts a value from an XML string using XPath
>   notation
>
> `UpdateXML()`:Return replaced XML fragment

Simplest example for executing `XML`  is:

```
SELECT ExtractValue('<NewDataSet><company><COM_CODE>Test Data</COM_CODE></company></NewDataSet>', '/NewDataSet/company/COM_CODE');//returns Test Data which is value inside <COM_CODE></COM_CODE>
```

For more see Mysql Docs [MYSQL XML Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/xml-functions.html)